# Deserialize Json into class object in C#

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to convert json to C# object.

My test code:

```
public class testvm
{
   public List<testclass> results { get; set; }    
}    

public class testclass
{
   public string item1 { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("string")]
   public string item2 { get; set; }
}    

static void jsonfun()
{    
   try
   {
      string json1 = @"{
      ""results"": [{
      ""item1"": ""testitem"" ,
      ""item2"": {
      ""string"": ""testitem2""
      }
      }]
      }";

      var obj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<testvm>(json1);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      { }
}
```

And output of above code as below
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq7WS.png)

AS we can see item2 is becoming null because json has one extra string tag.
Any suggestion how to map item2?

Comment: Seems like either your JSON is incorrectly formatted or item2 should be a list

Comment: Provide actual Json, it is not in correct format

Comment: json is in correct format , item1 also is same like item2 just to show the different i have removed string property from item1 .
i want to ignore this string tag from json and map the value with item2 property of class

Comment: Microsoft has a full tutorial on serialization in their site. See this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to).

Answer (score 0):

The testclass does not match the JSON object's format.

Your JSON looks like:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "item1": "testitem" ,
            "item2": {
                "string": "testitem2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So you models should look like:

```cs
public class TestClass
{
    public string item1 { get; set; }
    public TestClass2 item2 { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass2
{
    [JsonProperty("string")]
    public string someValue { get; set; }

}
```

And if you want to map it a specific client model

```cs
public class ClientModel {
    public string item1 {get;set;}
    public string item2 {get;set;}

}


// After deserialization do the map
var apiModel = JsonConvert.Deserialize([...])

var clientModel = new ClientModel {
  item1 = apiModel.item1,
  item2 = apiModel.item2.someValue
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for ur reply but there is anyway i can ignore this string property 
as its coming from some third party api result , but i dont want this should go to my client , i want to response simply 

{
    "results": [
        {
            "item1": "testitem" ,
            "item2":  "testitem2"
            
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Sure, you could just create a ClientTestClass to which you map the properties you want sent to the client.

In my opinion it's a bit cleaner having separate model classes for the 'input' and 'output'

Comment: I just updated the answer on how you can map it to a client model

Answer (score 0):

Update testclass to this: item2 is some how structure like a Dictionary.

```
public class testclass
{
    public string item1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("item2")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> item2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - I recommend you to use System.Text.Json instead of Newtonsoft.Json.

In .NET Core 3.0 and .NET 5 it works faster.

Then - you shouldn't use [JsonProperty()].

How to use System.Text.Json:

```
public class testvm
{
   public List<testclass> results { get; set; }
}

public class testclass
{
   public string item1 { get; set; }

   public string item2 { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   testvm objBeforeSerialization = new testvm() { results = new List<testclass>() { new testclass() { item1 = "myItem1", item2 = "myItem2" } } };
            
   string myJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(objBeforeSerialization);
                        
   testvm objAfterSerialization = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<testvm>(myJson);
}
```

JSON in string format will be like:

```
string stringObject = @"{""results"":[{""item1"":""myItem1"",""item2"":""myItem2""}]}";
```

You can read more about System.Text.Json in [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to).